# Generic type vector performances

Tags: c++

I need to have a vector class that is able to manage as set of predefined types and have the same performance as the standard std::vector.

I can't just rely on a simple template because the type isn't defined until run time. Bellow are two implementations I tested, but the first is about 4 times slower and the second 3 times slower than a simple std::vector. I also tested having a function pointer to the proper setValue that is assigned in the constructor, but it was 10 times slower.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TypeBase
{
public:
    virtual void setValue(int id, int value) = 0;
    virtual void setValue(int id, float value) = 0;
};

class TypeInt : public TypeBase
{
public:
    int* data;

    TypeInt(char* ptr)
    {
        data = (int*)ptr;
    }

    void setValue(int id, int value)
    {
        data[id] = value;
    }

    void setValue(int id, float value)
    {
        data[id] = (int)value;
    }
};

class TypeFloat : public TypeBase
{
public:
    float* data;

    TypeFloat(char* ptr)
    {
        data = (float*)ptr;
    }

    void setValue(int id, int value)
    {
        data[id] = (float)value;
    }

    void setValue(int id, float value)
    {
        data[id] = value;
    }
};

class genericTypeVector1
{
public:
    // Allow to get the right setValue
    TypeBase* typeMng = nullptr;
    // Vector storage
    std::vector<char> data;

    enum class Types {Int, Float};

    genericTypeVector1(Types type, size_t size)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case Types::Int:
            data.resize(size * sizeof(int));
            typeMng = new TypeInt(data.data());
            break;
        case Types::Float:
            data.resize(size * sizeof(float));
            typeMng = new TypeFloat(data.data());
            break;
        }
    }

    ~genericTypeVector1()
    {
        if (typeMng != nullptr)
            delete typeMng;
    }

    void setValue(int id, int value)
    {
        typeMng->setValue(id, value);
    }

    void setValue(int id, float value)
    {
        typeMng->setValue(id, value);
    }
};


class genericTypeVector2
{
public:
    // Vector storage
    std::vector<char> data;
    enum class Types { Int, Float };
    // Current type of the vector
    Types type;

    genericTypeVector2(Types type, size_t size)
        :type(type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case Types::Int:
            data.resize(size * sizeof(int));
            break;
        case Types::Float:
            data.resize(size * sizeof(float));
            break;
        }
    }

    void setValue(int id, int value)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case Types::Int:
            ((int*)data.data())[id] = value;
            break;
        case Types::Float:
            ((float*)data.data())[id] = (int)value;
            break;
        }
    }

    void setValue(int id, float value)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case Types::Int:
            ((int*)data.data())[id] = (float)value;
            break;
        case Types::Float:
            ((float*)data.data())[id] = value;
            break;
        }
    }
};

template<class T>
inline void setValue(T* ptr, int id, float value)
{
    ptr[id] = value;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 100000000;
    {
        std::vector<float> v(N);
        auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            v[i] = 2 * i - N;
        std::cout << "std::vector : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        genericTypeVector1 a(genericTypeVector1::Types::Float, N);
        auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            a.setValue(i, 2 * i - N);
        std::cout << "genericTypeVector with type manager : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        genericTypeVector2 a(genericTypeVector2::Types::Float, N);
        auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            a.setValue(i, 2 * i - N);
        std::cout << "genericTypeVector with switch-case in setValue : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        genericTypeVector2 a(genericTypeVector2::Types::Float, N);
        auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        switch (a.type)
        {
        case genericTypeVector2::Types::Int:
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                setValue((int*)a.data.data(), i, 2 * i - N);
            break;
        case genericTypeVector2::Types::Float:
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                setValue((float*)a.data.data(), i, 2 * i - N);
            break;         
        }
        std::cout << "genericTypeVector with switch case outside for loop : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I don't know what to try now. Perhaps I'm on a completely wrong path.
A added a last example that shows that it's possible to have the same performances as with a raw std::vector, but I don't want to have this switch-case every time I call setValue.

Comment: `std::vector<std::variant<Ts...>>`  or `std::vector<std::any>>` ?

Comment: By your attempts it looks like you are trying to implement something like  std::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<float>>

Comment: ... but the alignment in the `std::vector<char>` can't be trusted to store your types

Comment: You simply can't make it as fast with a type determined at runtime. You might get slightly better than a factor of three, but I would be surprised if you got much faster than that.

Comment: Side notes: member functions defined inside a class definition are implicitly `inline` (which does not mean what you think it means), and it's impossible for the compiler to inline a virtual function call.

Comment: One way to mitigate virtual call in loop is to have a virtual method which does the loop, something like `virtual void setValues(int id1, id2, std::function<int(int)> generator) = 0;` (unfortunately, `std::function` usage would be similar to a virtual call, but it clarify the idea I think ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

[Edit]
I redo my whole answer now that I've looked at the code and ran it! One thing BTW from a benchmarking standpoint -- you have code like this:

```
genericTypeVector2 a(genericTypeVector2::Types::Float, N);
auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    a.setValue(i, 2 * i - N);
std::cout << "genericTypeVector with switch-case in setValue : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
```

The time measurements don't begin until after the data structure is initialized. I was wondering why on earth your final version was beating `std::vector` when it still involved dynamic dispatch:

```
std::vector : 46ms
genericTypeVector with type manager : 182ms
genericTypeVector with switch-case in setValue : 115ms
genericTypeVector with switch case outside for loop : 44ms
```

.. until I looked at your code more carefully and realized you weren't factoring in times to construct the structure.`std::vector` is often aggresively optimized in terms of the functions it uses for constructing and destroying PODs, able to do things like a `calloc` if the type is trivially default-constructible (although it still often just uses a plain old placement new loop for fill constructors) in which case it might not even need to touch the memory until you begin to access it via `operator[]`. So with the way you're measuring, the bulk of the overhead of paging and cache misses are likely incurred by vector in its timing (I need to profile to make sure but this seems most likely), while your version incurs them outside of when you actually begin measuring the times.

So I fixed the test and got these times which is closer to my expectations from having repeatedly benchmarked and profiled similar code:

```
std::vector : 109ms
genericTypeVector with type manager : 276ms
genericTypeVector with switch-case in setValue : 191ms
genericTypeVector with switch case outside for loop : 131ms
```

And that's not too bad unless you have a real-world case where just setting values of array elements in a loop is showing up as one of your bigger hotspots. It's easy to get cross-eyed trying to do these ultra granular performance tests and think 3-4x slower is so bad when most domains involve more meaty processing over each element (unless we're talking about image processing or something like that).

But the main overhead I suspect is just the extra branching for the dynamic dispatch in all your cases (two layers for version 1, one for version 2) + `switch` overhead.

One thing you can possibly do about the `switch` versions is to use `__assume(0)` in MSVC or goto labels in GCC. It's a trick I learned optimizing interpreters. You can get a much improvement in performance if the switch branching is dominating the times since both of these solutions eliminate an extra branch required for what would otherwise be a default case when you handle all possible cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "the most intuitive level"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number For example, suppose we're designing a video game in an object-oriented fashion. The intuitive way to abstract the game objects is at the level of an individual game object, like `Elf`, not `Elves`. But if performance is most critical, it can help to abstract at the coarser level of `Elves`, even though it's a bit counter-intuitive and more cumbersome to code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So instead of `Elf` deriving from `GameObject`, we have `Elves` deriving from `GameObjects`. The cost of indirect calls is now trivialized to a per-container level, not a per-element level, but far more importantly, we can now start storing elves in bulk and generally or largely contiguously (in `std::vector` or whatever other container is appropriate).

Comment: ok thanks. I wasnt sure what you mean. Actually I think the wording is a little misunderandable (because once you know what to do, your intuition is to do the right thing). Nevermind, its a nitpick on wording in an otherwise nice answer imho

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number My bad! I got a comment on that in a previous post of mine. I'm very lazy and bad with my terminology and also from Japan and English is not my native language. So apologies for the ambiguities of the way I write.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number My wife complains that I think and talk like a woman. She's not talking about the sound of my voice but I'm all over the place! But I am more concerned with the feeling than the facts. I feel like if a developer is struggling a lot in spite of studying a lot of facts, he/she needs to get the right "feeling". I hope that's not so vague! I tend to drive my colleagues crazy with my imprecise language, metaphors, analogies, but I really think the facts are like tools and the feeling/vision more important since they pave the path on how to use them.

Comment: @AntiGamer Thank you for your analysis. I think you are wrong about the zigzagging implied by the usage of a char vector to store other types. There is no reason for the data not being contiguous because they are stored in a sorted:: vector, which should store data contiguously. A simple tests show that an std:: vector<float> or an std:: vector<char> to store a vector of float gives exactly the same performance. I edited my initial question with a new case which has the same performance as the raw std::vector case.

Comment: @Awen I see! I had a more careful look now at your code and ran it myself. I see you're already abstracting at the container level although with a dynamic dispatch per setting a value. Most of the overhead I think in this case might be branching. With such teeny data types and PODs at that, even the cost of a simple lone `if` statement in a function to access or mutate one element becomes relatively quite expensive... but not necessarily so in lots of real world scenarios assuming you're doing more heavy computation and/or that they're bigger than teeny 32-bit PODs.

Comment: @Awen I updated my answer after examining your code more closely!